# CakePHP pdf plugin unable to print image if I use dompdf engine

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am using [FriendsOfCake/cakepdf](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/CakePdf/tree/3.x) to generate PDF. I am unable to print image in pdf

I have used below configuration in bootstrap.php

```
Configure::write('CakePdf', [
    'engine' => 'CakePdf.DomPdf',
     'margin' => [
         'bottom' => 15,
         'left' => 50,
         'right' => 30,
          'top' => 45
      ],
      'orientation' => 'landscape',
      'download' => false,
      'isRemoteEnabled' => true,
      'isHtml5ParserEnabled' => true,
      'debugKeepTemp' => true
]);
```

I have used a simple pdflayout, layout/pdf/pdf.ctp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?= $this->Html->charset() ?>
</head>
<body>
    <?= $this->fetch('content') ?>               
</body>
</html>
```

MY pdf/view.ctp

```
<div>
  <?= $this->Html->image('banner.png', ['fullBase' => true]); ?>
</div>
```

My pdf has made like below

[image]

How can I print image in pdf ? Am I missing any settings ?

```
My cake php version : 3.6.15 
"friendsofcake/cakepdf": "^3.3",
```

Comment: What does `$this->Html->image('banner.png', ['fullBase' => true])` give you? Is it a valid URL that the system generating the PDF is able to reference?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have a banner,png file in my webroot/img folder. I am also not able to connec bootstrap for PDF.

Comment: That in no way answers my question.

Comment: @GregSchmidt sorry, pardon me. I not understood your question clearly, "valid URL that the system generating the PDF" how can I check it ?

Comment: Let me try again. First, when you call `$this->Html->image('banner.png', ['fullBase' => true])`, what is the output? I'm not looking for an answer like "It's the banner image", I mean exactly what URL do you get from that call?

Comment: @GregSchmidt I have got the URL after debug in pdf is  : '<img src="http://localhost/cakeproject/img/banner.png" alt=""/>' 
After ping url I am able to see image in browser.

Comment: @GregSchmidt Thanks for your clue ! I have changed dompdf to tcpdf , and now it's working fine.

Comment: @NiloyRony I am facing the same issue, I am not able to print the image in the PDF I tried to change Tcpdf but it didn't worked.

Comment: @AliAbbas 
<img src="webroot/img/myimage.jpeg">  it's work in tcpdf. Without DOM pdf I have successfully print image almost all pdf engine. If you are not using share hosting I recommend WkHtmlToPdf engine for best result.